# Wpf listview scroll does not work properly in drag and drop scenario

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, drag-and-drop

I have the following Xaml code

```
    <ListView x:Name="ListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Values}" MaxHeight="400" MaxWidth="500" MinWidth="160"
              VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"  ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True"
              MouseMove="ListView_MouseMove">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView x:Name="GridView" ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}">
                <!--<GridViewColumn Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding [0]}"  CellTemplate="{StaticResource ColumnCellTemplate}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Test" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding [1]}" CellTemplate="{StaticResource ColumnCellTemplate}"/>-->
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

and the relevant code behind for my issue as follows

```
 Private Sub ListView_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnMouseMove(e)
        Dim viewModel As QuestionAnswerViewModel = CType(DataContext, QuestionAnswerViewModel)
       'Dim vis As Visual = e.OriginalSource()
        If e.LeftButton = MouseButtonState.Pressed And viewModel IsNot Nothing AndAlso viewModel.Value IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim data As New DataObject
            data.SetData(DataFormats.StringFormat, viewModel.Value)

            'Inititate the drag-and-drop operation.
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(Me, data, DragDropEffects.Copy Or DragDropEffects.Move)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Now the problem with my code is that when I scroll the MouseMove event gets triggered and then, of course the drag and drop method. I wanted to ask how can I properly use the `e.OriginalSource()` method in order to see if the user is dragging or not the scroll-bar.

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand your problem, could you reword it please

Comment: I click and drag the scroll bar. The MouseMove event gets triggered and it goes inside the IF statement. The DoDragDrop method gets executed and of course it hinders the functionality of the ScrollViewer. The code should go in the IF statement only if I am dragging a ListViewItem. I hope this makes a bit more clear...

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the the scroll working properly I have just added a new check in the `If` statement `Not e.OriginalSource().GetType().Equals(GetType(Thumb))`

The full code looks like this now

```
  Private Sub ListView_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnMouseMove(e)
        Dim viewModel As QuestionAnswerViewModel = CType(DataContext, QuestionAnswerViewModel)

        If e.LeftButton = MouseButtonState.Pressed And viewModel IsNot Nothing AndAlso viewModel.Value IsNot Nothing _
                AndAlso Not e.OriginalSource().GetType().Equals(GetType(Thumb)) Then
            Dim data As New DataObject
            data.SetData(DataFormats.StringFormat, viewModel.Value)

            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(Me, data, DragDropEffects.Copy Or DragDropEffects.Move)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Now whenever I drag the scroll bar the code will not go inside the `If` statement, therefore the scroll bar will work properly.